# MySQL value of date

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have problem with my code.

I have JavaEE app with MySQL db. I have object which have variable dateOfBirth. If I set this variable to 20/5/1978 and save the form, the value si changed to 19/5/1978. Via debug I find the value is 19/5/1978 23:00:00. I have some problem with time zone. (but it is not for every date...come problem with summer time?)

Connection to DB is:

```
?useUnicode=true&useGmtMillisForDatetimes=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=Europe/Prague
```

and system_time_zone on server is CET, time_zone is SYSTEM.

Some tips how to solve it? I am clueless.

I forgot, the value in DB is correct! I use primefaces, but I am using own date converter, which return the same problem as "default".
In java I use get a set fot:

```
@NotNull(message = "{client.birthDate.NotNull}")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date birthDate;
```

EDIT: I use this converter

```
@ApplicationScoped
@Named(value = "dateTimeConverter")
@FacesConverter("dateTimeConverter")
public class DateTimeConverter implements Converter {


    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, 
    String value) {
        System.out.println("v:" + value);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
        Date date = sdf.parse(value);
        System.out.println("f:" + date);
        return date;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, 
    Object value) {
        System.out.println("to:" + value.toString()); //HERE I get 
    19/05/1978!!!
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
        System.out.println("timezone:" + sdf.getTimeZone());
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Prague"));
        String date = sdf.format(value);
        System.out.println("s:" + date);
        return date;
    }
}
```

EDIT2:

```
<p:calendar id="#{id}_birthDate" placeholder="#{msg.BirthDate}" yearRange="c-100:c" value="#{client.birthDate}" navigator="true" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" disabled="#{ViewBean.z.locked}"> <f:converter converterId="dateTimeConverter"/> <p:ajax listener="#{ViewBean.invalidate()}" update="@(.buttonPanelClass)" event="dateSelect"/> </p:calendar>
```

Comment: Perhaps you can [edit] your question and post the java code that retrieves the value from the database?

Comment: does mysql change the data or the java form? Reading some mysql docs seems that useLegacyDatetimeCode=false will not let the other parameters you sent for time to take effect :/ ...

Comment: I try it, but it is the same :(

Comment: how the date look like in primeface? (code)

Comment: <p:calendar id="#{id}_birthDate" placeholder="#{msg.BirthDate}"
                                yearRange="c-100:c" value="#{client.birthDate}" navigator="true"
                                pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" disabled="#{ViewBean.z.locked}">
                        <f:converter converterId="dateTimeConverter"/>
                        <p:ajax listener="#{ViewBean.invalidate()}"
                                update="@(.buttonPanelClass)" event="dateSelect"/>
                    </p:calendar>